# Qual a diferença entre matriz unidimensional e bidimensional?

Tags: matriz, matemática

No ensino médio geralmente estudamos sobre o conceito de Matriz, que consiste de uma tabela de linha e colunas formando um conjunto de números ou elementos.

Na matemática, na programação e em outras áreas utilizamos Matrizes então gostaria de saber a diferença entre matriz unidimensional e bidimensional?

Como declarar uma matriz unidimensional e uma bidimensional?

> Gostaria de exemplos em algumas linguagens, ex: **java**, **php**, **c++** se
>   possível.

Answer (score 7):

Matriz unidimensional possui apenas uma dimensão. Também é chamada de vetor. Em pseudolinguagem:

```
var vetor = inteiro[10];
```

Em Java:

```
int[] vetor = new int[10];
```

Em C++:

```
int vetor[10];
```

Matriz bidimensional possui duas dimensões. Em pseudolinguagem:

```
var matriz = inteiro[10, 10];
```

Em Java:

```
int[][] vetor = new int[10][10];
```

Em C++:

```
int vetor[10][10];
```

Comment: Você não pede isto em sua pergunta. A resposta atende ao que foi perguntado. Se precisa de mais detalhes, coloque isto claramente na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Matriz unidimensional, também tratada como "vetor", armazena dados de forma sequencial, e cada dado é armazenado e recuperado por meio de um número inteiro que representa a sua "posição" nesta "fileira". Por representar uma "reta", pode-se dizer que os dados são armazenados em uma única dimensão.

A declaração vai depender da linguagem, usualmente:

```
Dim Vetor(15)
```

Neste exemplo foi criado um vetor (de nome "Vetor") que comporta 16 elementos (dados distintos), pois todo vetor inicia do 0 (zero).

A matriz bidimensional armazena dados por meio de dois números inteiros, que representam a "posição" de cada dado na matriz, como em um eixo cartesiano onde, por exemplo, pode-se considerar pontos a valores de números inteiros e positivos (incluindo zeros). Assim, cada par de valores indicam um dado distinto. Como representam dois eixos, que formam um "plano" (x e y em geometria), ela representa valores em duas dimensões.

Usualmente a declaração seria:

```
Dim Matriz(5; 4)
```

Neste exemplo foi criada uma matriz (de nome "Matriz") que comporta 30  elementos (dados distintos), pois como os valores 0 (zero) devem ser considerados, a quantidade de itens que esta matriz pode armazenar se calcula por: 6 X 5 = 30.

Answer (score 2):

Bom as respostas estão acima, eu só queria colocar um desenho acho que contribuirá para o entendimento.

Imagine que estou querendo armazenar dados de pessoas.

Matriz unidimensional:

```
João | Vitor | Pedro | Adriana
```

Como pode-se ver acima ficaria complicado armazenar a idade, sexo, etc de uma mesma pessoa, pois eu só tenho uma linha na matriz. A matriz bidimensional resolve isto também, pois agora cada linha da matriz terá dados de uma pessoa.

Matriz bidimensional:

Então ficará assim:

```
João | 18 | Masculino | Desenvolvedor

Vitor | 22 | Masculino | Analista

Pedro | 35 | Masculino | Arquiteto

Adriana | 24 | Feminino | Web Design
```

A diferença é que a matriz unidimensional possui apenas uma dimensão, apenas uma linha.